# IE8 XMLHttpRequest Send not Working

Tags: json, http, post, internet-explorer-8, request

I am trying to make a send POST request using XMLHttpRequest but its not working..

I don't watch any call to my url at fiddler..

The console of IE developer tools don't show any error..

And I can see all the alert boxes.

Also I enabled the "Access data sources across domains" option in Internet Zone, Intranet Zone, and I also added my localhost to the trusted sites..

Does anyone has some clue?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function callService(id) {

    id.innerHTML = "Clicked!";
    alert("Antes do XMLHttpRequest!");
        var xmlhttp;
    try {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (ex) {
            xmlhttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    alert("Antes do url!");
    var url = "https://localhost:1234/blabla/blabla";

    alert("Antes do open!");


    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    alert("Antes do setRequestHeader!");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    alert("Antes do onreadystatechange!");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    alert("Antes do parameters!");
    var parameters = JSON.stringify({"Values": {"Value": 2500,"ItemNumber": "1"},"PartnerID": "SUB","ProdCode": "CEC","Session": "321","OpCode": "10"});

    alert("Antes do send!");
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);
    alert("Depois do send!!");

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 onclick="callService(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bad link I was invoking .

Problem solved ;)